# C#: como crear carpetas con sub carpetas en cualquier direccion

Tags: c#

necesito crear carpetas con subcarpetas al presionar un boton, para eso tengo este codigo

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
var pathEscritorio = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) 
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(pathEscritorio + @"\carpeta 1");

dir.CreateSubdirectory("subcarpeta1");
dir.CreateSubdirectory("subcarpeta2");
```

intente con este codigo pero me da error ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, estaria muy agradecido

Comment: para obtener la ruta del escritorio es  var pathEscritorio = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

Comment: ¿como se debe usar **pathEscritorio** en la direccion? intente escribiendo "pathEscritorio\\Nueva carpeta" pero no funciono

Comment: Con una applicacion Windows Forms puede usar el clase OpenFileDialog().

Comment: Y la ruta `pathEscritorio + @"\carpeta 1"` existe, si no existe arrojara una exception. Por lo tanto si no existe la debes crear y luego crear las subcarpetas. Ademas si mal y no me equivoco puede combinar las rutas utilizando `Path.Combine` mas sobre [DirectoryInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8) y [Path.Combine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas que tu carpeta y sus subcarpetas se creen siempre en el escritorio, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)+"\\Nueva carpeta");

dir.CreateSubdirectory("subcarpeta1");
dir.CreateSubdirectory("subcarpeta2");

}
```

Si lo que deseas que el usuario de de tu aplicación pueda elegir el camino donde colocar tus subcarpetas, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        
      FolderBrowserDialog folderBrs = new FolderBrowserDialog();
      //Mostramos el cuadro de dialogo de exploracion de capetas
      if (folderBrs.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         //Si el usuario seleccionó una ruta valida entonces la asignamos al objeto System.IO.DirectoryInfo
          System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderBrs.SelectedPath);
    
          dir.CreateSubdirectory("subcarpeta1");
          dir.CreateSubdirectory("subcarpeta2");
    
      }
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba :D

Comment: @DavidChavero. Me complace que mi modesto aporte, te haya resultado útil.

Comment: disculpa, en el segundo codigo donde el usuario elige la ruta, el codigo funciona bien, solo que el problema es que solo se crean las dos subcarpetas ¿sabes como podria hacer para que se cree la carpeta con las subcarpetas?

Comment: @DavidChavero Muy sencillo, solo en tu linea de código donde creas el objeto  `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` incluyes el nombre de tu carpeta  `System.IO.DirectoryInfo
          System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderBrs.SelectedPath+"\\Nueva carpeta");`

Answer (score 1):

usa lo siguiente:

```
string nombreFolder= "NuevaCarpeta";

string rutaNuevoFolder= System.IO.Path.Combine(
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
   nombreFolder);
  //verificamos que no exista y entonces se crea
if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(rutaNuevoFolder)) {
   try {
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(rutaNuevoFolder);
   } catch (IOException ie) {
      Console.WriteLine("IO Error: " + ie.Message);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("General Error: " + e.Message);
   }
}
```